# How to generate reports from MOSS survey List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, survey-list, survey

I would like to generate reports from `MOSS Survey list` since out of the box options are very limited. I would like to `publish` this report to SharePoint so that users can view and download this report. Report should contain real time data. I tried using `SSRS` report as suggested in the below blog. Since survey having Ranking columns, I am not able to properly generate the report since the data is stored in this format

*e.g : The opportunity to use your abilities and skills such as decision making, autonomy and challenging projects;#3#Recognition for the work you did;#3#Available opportunities for career development;#5#*

Any alternative approach is very much appreciated.

SharePoint List data in SSRS Report Reference blog : http://nikpatel.net/2010/04/30/step-by-step-consuming-sharepoint-lists-data-in-the-ssrs-reports/

Comment: Can anybody help?